# Is there a direct way to get a full ejb/servlet application example for glassfish

Tags: servlets, glassfish, ejb

I have an application that is currently running on JBoss AS but does not work on Glassfish.  I'm trying to work through the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/javaeetutorial6.pdf) but I'm having trouble figuring out things like what the file structure of the application should be and what (if any) additional files are needed.  This documentation also refers to examples but to get the examples you need to install Netbeans and access an update tool tied to the glassfish instance installed with Netbeans.  When I do this the server won't start, the update tool won't run, and I can't get the examples.  Is there an easy way to get these examples (e.g. a simple download)? I've found other examples such as [this one](https://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/a-simple-ejb-3-0-example-with-jsp-and-servlet/), but they are also dependent upon Netbeans.

Is there a simple and complete ejb/servlet example for Glassfish that can be simply downloaded and does not depend upon Netbeans or other IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious example is the [Java EE CargoTracker](https://github.com/javaee/cargotracker). It was written to show what a "real" application might look like with pure Java EE APIs so should work on both JBoss and GlassFish. You will need Maven installed to build and run it, but there are more complete details in the readme for the project. Note that some of the information is a little out of date (mostly links to java.net which has been sunset in favour of a GitHub site) but the application itself is still a good example of Java EE 7 APIs.

https://github.com/javaee/cargotracker

Comment: Thanks, this was hugely helpful.  There is a wealth of information on the j2ee github site (https://github.com/javaee) including the example you've given as well as other smaller examples (https://github.com/javaee/glassfish-samples) as well as a bunch of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I found the examples on github here:

https://github.com/javaee/glassfish-samples

To get and build the examples you will need Git and Maven.  These examples are small, complete, and concise.  The example that was helpful for my particular problem was this example:

glassfish-samples\ws\javaee5\enterprise\servlet-stateless-ear

It demonstrated that I needed to change the structure of my project such that the servlet was in a .war file and not in a .jar file in the lib folder of my project.

Comment: There are also lots of samples for both [Java EE 7](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples) and [Java EE 8](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee8-samples)